# Pandas function to group by cumulative sum and return another column when a certain amount is reached

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby, nested-lists, cumulative-sum

Here it is my problem.
I got a dataframe like this:

```
ID   item   amount   level
1     1      10       5
1     1      10       10
2     4      15       5
2     9      30       8
2     4      10       10
2     4      10       20
3     4      10       4
3     4      10       6
```

and I need to know, per each id, at what level the cumulative sum of each item reaches a fixed amount.
For example, If I need to know the first time when a given items reach an amount of 20 or more for a user.
I would like to have something like:

```
ID   item   amount   level
1     1      10       5
1     1      20       10
2     4      15       5
2     9      30       8
2     4      25       10
2     4      40       20
3     4      10       4
3     4      20       6
```

and then something like a list or a dictionary in which I can store the results. for example:

```
d[item_number] = [list_of_levels_per_id_when_20_is_reached]
```

In this example:

```
{1: [10], 4: [10,6], 9: [8]}
```

Comment: Can you provide the expected output?

Comment: The final dictionary is the output! If you can also provide the code for the group by would be great, but not necessary

Comment: What would be the dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### cumsum

You can perform the cumsum post group with:

```
df['amount_cumsum'] = df.groupby(['ID', 'item'])['amount'].cumsum()
```

Output (as separate column for clarity):

```
   ID  item  amount  level  amount_cumsum
0   1     1      10      5             10
1   1     1      10     10             20
2   2     4      15      5             15
3   2     9      30      8             30
4   2     4      10     10             25
5   3     4      10      4             10
6   3     4      10      6             20
```

##### dictionary

```
(df[df['amount_cumsum'].ge(20)]
 .groupby(['item'])['level'].agg(list)
 .to_dict()
 )
```

Output:

```
{1: [10], 4: [10, 6], 9: [8]}
```

Comment: I added more info in the question. Is your code still good for my case?

Comment: Yes, give it a try!

Comment: Just to check, I need just to know the level of the first time a given user reaches the fixed amount. I player X reached 20 units of an item at level 10, and I'm not interested in the other levels. It sees that your code doesn't keep that into consideration. Am I wrong? I sit possible to filter the df after the .get(20) so that I keep only the first row of each user?